# Powershell substring before first int

Tags: powershell, int, substring

I am needing to cut what powershell sees as 1 line into 2 variables. I used `-split [Environment]::NewLine` and it made some lines look like the following.

```
abc
12.3
```

The bottom will always be an integer. Is there a substring to fist integer I could sue to assign each row to a variable?

Thanks for your help.

```
GIGM
2.51
+0.19
8.30
25.47M
11.66
9.78
-5.16

CARB
9.83
+0.75
8.26
260.44M
-
122.62
-9.35

TRT
3.10
+0.22
7.64
10.92M
11.68
33.93
0.52

MXPT
1.61
+0.11
7.33
39.89M
-
106.46
-12.99
```

Comment: `12.3` is not an integer. Also, can you give an example of one of these strings and the `-split` pattern argument you used to split it

Comment: I updated the question with info you requested.

Comment: @Shale I edited your question to add formatting blocks to make it easier to read. If you feel it changed the presentation too much, let me know and I can roll it back. Cheers!

Comment: @NateBarbettini, Thanks I am bad at the formatting on this site.

Answer (score 1):

something like this could be used

```
"abc`n12.3" -split "`n" | % {
    if ($_ -as [int]) {
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `0` valid `int` value?

Comment: nope. 0 gives false. hoping someone can give a more accurate answer.

Comment: How about `$null -ne ('0' -as [int])`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I figured a way out. I was doing -replace "&amp.*". I changed it to -replace "&"," ", and then another replace for -replace "amp.*". This allowed me to use the Blank area as a divider and powershell then separated the non number lines into their own lines instead of combining them with the first line of numbers.

Comment: FYI, you should put the whole code snippet for your solution in this answer. If you need to, you can add additional details to your original question by editing it.